# Python with MySql unicode problems

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I need to call MySQL stored procedure from my python script. As one of parameters I'm passing a unicode string (Russian language), but I get an error;

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(256)

My script:

```
  self.db=MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "usr", "pass", "dbName")
  self.cursor=self.db.cursor()
  args=("какой-то текст") #this is string in russian
  self.cursor.callproc('pr_MyProc', args)
  self.cursor.execute('SELECT @_pr_MyProc_2') #getting result from sp
  result=self.cursor.fetchone()
  self.db.commit()
```

I've read that setting `charset='utf8'` shuld resolve this problem, but when I use string:

```
self.db=MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "usr", "pass", "dbName", charset='utf8')
```

This gives me another error;

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udcd1' in position 20: surrogates not allowed

Also I've trying to set parametr `use_unicode=True`, that's not working.

Comment: Does it work if you send the string in unicode: `args=(u"какой-то текст")`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman no, I've tryed it too.

Comment: is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366479/python-3-os-walk-file-paths-unicodeencodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-encode-s

Comment: what's also strange is that that Cyrillic (?) string can be decoded into UTF-8 without issue.

Comment: Have you tried charset='utf-16'. probably this help.

Answer (score 5):

More things to check on:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python

Likely items:

- Start code file with `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` -- (for literals in code)
- Literals should be u'...'

Can you extract the HEX?  `какой-то текст` should be this in utf8: `D0BA D0B0 D0BA D0BE D0B9 2D D182 D0BE D182 20 D0B5 D0BA D181 D182`

Comment: As I understand "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" sets encoding for file, not for strings. So it does'not help.

Comment: Does it hurt in your situation?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some thoughts. Maybe not a response. I've been playing with python/mysql/utf-8/unicode in the past and this is the things i remember:

Looking at Saltstack mysql module's comment :

https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/develop/salt/modules/mysql.py#L314-L322

```
# MySQLdb states that this is required for charset usage
# but in fact it's more than it's internally activated
# when charset is used, activating use_unicode here would
# retrieve utf8 strings as unicode() objects in salt
# and we do not want that.
#_connarg('connection_use_unicode', 'use_unicode')
connargs['use_unicode'] = False
_connarg('connection_charset', 'charset')
```

We see that to avoid altering the result string the use_unicode is set to False, while the charset (which could be utf-8) is set as a parameter. use_unicode is more a 'request' to get responses as unicode strings.

You can check real usage in the tests, here: 
https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/develop/tests/integration/modules/test_mysql.py#L311-L361 with a database named '標準語'.

Now about the message **UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udcd1' **. You are using **unicode** but you tell the module it is **utf-8**. It is not **utf-8** until you encode your unicode string in utf-8.

Maybe you should try with:

```
args=(u"какой-то текст".encode('utf-8'))
```

At least in python3 this is required, because your "какой-то текст" is not in utf-8 by default.

Comment: Link is now broken: I found the new link: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/develop/tests/integration/modules/test_mysql.py#L311-L361 (Note file_name change)

Answer (score 2):

The MySQLdb module is not compatible with python 3. That might be why you are getting problems. I would advise to use a different connector, like [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL%20%22PyMySQL) or [mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient).

Related: [23376103](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23376103/python-3-4-0-with-mysql-database).

Comment: I'm using mysqlclinet

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can reload your `sys` in `utf-8` and try to decode the string into `utf-8` as following :

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

...

stringUtf8 = u''.join(string_original).decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem very recently but with PostgreSQL. After trying tons of suggestions from SO/ internet, I realized the issue was with my database. I had to drop my database and reinstall Postgres, because for some reason it was not allowing me to change the database's default collation. I was in a hurry so couldn't find a better solution, but would recommend the same, since I was only starting my application in the deployment environment.
All the best.

Answer (score 1):

What's your database's charset?

use :

```
show variables like "characetr%";
```

or see your database's charset

Answer (score 1):

I see here two problems.

1. You have unicode but you try to define it as utf-8 by setting parameter "charset". You should first encode your unicode to utf-8 or another encoding system.
2. If it however doesn't work, try to do so with **init_command='SET NAMES UTF8'** parameter.

So it will look like:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(charset='utf8', init_command='SET NAMES UTF8')
```

You can try also this:

```
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("SET NAMES UTF8;")
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue, which was caused by invalid utf-8 data in the database; it seems that MySQL doesn't care about that, but Python does, because it's following the UTF-8 spec, which says [that](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf8-4):

- surrogate pairs are not allowed in utf-8
- unpaired surrogates are not allowed in utf-8

If you want to "make it work", you'll have to intercept the MySQL packet and use your own converter which will perform ad-hoc replacements.

Here's one way to "handle" invalid data containing surrogates:

```
def borked_utf8_decode(data):
    """
    Work around input with unpaired surrogates or surrogate pairs,
    replacing by XML char refs: look for "&#\d+;" after.
    """
    return data.decode("utf-8", "surrogatepass") \
     .encode("utf-8", "xmlcharrefreplace") \
     .decode("utf-8")
```

Note that the proper way to handle that is context-dependent, but there are some common replacement scenarios, like [this one](https://github.com/jagracey/Awesome-Unicode#calculating-surrogate-pairs).

And here's one way of plugging this into `pymysql` (another way is to monkey-patch field processing, see eg. https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/631):

```
import pymysql.converters

# use this in your connection
pymysql_use_unicode = False
conversions = pymysql.converters.conversions
conversions[pymysql.converters.FIELD_TYPE.STRING] = borked_utf8_decode
conversions[pymysql.converters.FIELD_TYPE.VAR_STRING] = borked_utf8_decode
conversions[pymysql.converters.FIELD_TYPE.VARCHAR] = borked_utf8_decode
```