How is it possible to encode character '\ud83d' in python?
I read data from salesforce and put this into a pandas dataframe. When I try to print the result I get an unicode encode error.
First I read data from source and put the result into a pandas dataframe.
# query to execute
sql_code = """ Select Id, ResponseShortText FROM SurveyQuestionResponse """

# get data
df_xyz_raw = pd.DataFrame(sf.query_all(query = sql_code)["records"])

When I print the result a get this error.
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ud83d' in position 229: surrogates not allowed
I try to encode and decode the data.
df_xyz_raw ["ResponseShortText"] = df_xyz_raw ["ResponseShortText"].str.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore').str.decode('utf-8')

This works but only because of errors=ignore.
I think it is an emoji which is not part of utf-8? Does that mean that the source system is using another unicode format in comparison to utf-8 in my python environment?
Is their any way to handle these character and print them?

Try something like '\ud83d\udc3d'.encode( 'utf-16', errors='surrogatepass').decode( 'utf-16', errors='ignore'). Returns `` (U+1F43D, PIG NOSE).

I think this (\ud83d) is the first part of a pair. see: How can I convert surrogate pairs to normal string in Python?


If it's a lone surrogate, then there is some form of data corruption occuring. 2) if it's part of a surrogate pair then it would be useful to know what data is actually in the data frame cell. It may be JSON with escaped characters. If passing through a Java pipeline it may be MUTF-8. If the database is using older encoding or collation solutions for Unicode it may be CESU-8. JoaefZ's code will fix the dataframe if it's part of a surrogate pair. But it would be better to know what the root problem with the data is and address problem upstream.


@user19077881 Have you run your code? I get the same UnicodeEncodeError when I run your code.

@user19077881 Interesting, indeed. I'd argue that's a bug, because there is no character at that code point.

Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536539/unicodeencodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-encode-character-ud83d-in-position-38

I'll give some background to what is occurring, provide a few workarounds. The codepoint \ud83d is a High Surrogate, and does not exist as a Unicode character in and of itself. Plane 0 (the Basic Multiplingual Plane) contains the Unicode codepoints 0x0000–0xD7FF and 0xE000–0xFFFF. The characters 0xD800–0xDFFF are reserved for surrogate pairs and should not occur in Python string objects.
The encodings UTF-16, MUTF-8 and CESU-8 encode characters from 0x10000 onwards as a pair of codepoints (refered to as surrogate pairs). The made up of a high surrogate (0xD800–0xDBFF) and a low surrogate (0xDC00–0xDFFF).
If we take the cat emoji (U+1F408) as an example:
s = ''
print('UTF-8: ', s.encode('utf-8').hex(' ').upper())
# UTF-8:  F0 9F 90 88
print('UTF-16-BE: ', s.encode('utf-16-be').hex(' ').upper())
# UTF-16-BE:  D8 3D DC 08

In UTF-8 it is represented as a sequence of four bytes representing a single Unicode codepoint, U+1F408. In UTF-16 it is a sequence of four bytes representing a surrogate pair U+D83D U+DC08.
There are two scenarios likely in your data:

U+D83D is the first character in a surrogate pair, or
U+D83D is a lone surrogate (with no matching low surrogate character.)

In scenario one, the data is most likely been imported in without proper transcoding of the data between data formats or character encodings. Possible sources of the data are ASCII-safe JSON data, where characters above U+FFFF are escaped as surrogate pairs. Other sources for of the surrogate pairs include Java data pipelines using the MUTF-8 encoding or a database using CESU-8 encoding and failure to convert between encodings when data is retrieved via SQL or exported form database.
In this discussion I will assume that U+D83D is the first character in a surrogate pair representing an emoji. This is the most common senario for the average developer, unless you are the rare breed working with historical writing systems or minority language writing systems.
For instance to get a list of emoji (using PyICU) that are represented by a surrogate pair where the high surrogate is U+D83D:
import icu
emoji = icu.UnicodeSet(r'\p{Emoji}')
hs = "\ud83d"  # high surrogate
hs_byte = hs.encode('utf-16-be', 'surrogatepass')
suspected_emoji = [e for e in list(emoji) if e.encode('utf-16-be').startswith(hs_byte)]
print(suspected_emoji)

Scenario one: surrogate pairs
It is necessary to first encode then decode the surrogate pair using a UTF-16 codec. A MUTF-8 or CESU-8 codec could also be used, but this aren't standard encodings supported by Python.
emoji = '\uD83D\uDC08'
print(emoji)

Will give a UnicodeEncodeError exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: surrogates not allowed

Likewise emoji.encode('utf-16').decode('utf-16') will also give result in an UnicodeEncodeError exception, so we need to use the surrogatepass error handler:
r = emoji.encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass').decode('utf-16')
print(r)
# 

When working with a dataframe:
import pandas as pd
data = {
    "user": ["Charlie", "Anna"],
    "message": ["I need to feed my \uD83D\uDC08", "What will you give her?"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Various operations on the dataframe will result in will result in a UnicodeEncodeError exception. For instance df.head() will result in the error.
Like a string we can use an encode/decode sequence:
df['message'] = df['message'].str.encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass').str.decode('utf-16')
df.head()

Scenario 2: lone surrogate
If we use the same code syntax as in scenario 1 we get a UnicodeDecodeError exception. The codec can't handle a lone surrogate. An alternative error handler can be used, such as ignore, replace or backslashreplace. Or a custom error handler could be used:
lone = 'a lone surrogate: \uD83D'
res = lone.encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass').decode('utf-16', 'replace')
print("replace error handler: ", res)
# replace error handler:  a lone surrogate: �

Translating that to a dataframe:
import pandas as pd
data = {
    "user": ["Charlie", "Anna"],
    "message": ["I need to feed my \uD83D", "What will you give her?"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['message'] = df['message'].str.encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass').str.decode('utf-16', 'replace')
df.head()

Addendum
If you want to get a list of all surrogate pairs with a specific high surrogate value:

import icu
non_bmp = icu.UnicodeSet(r'[[[\p{Any}]-[\u0000-\uFFFF]]-[\p{Unassigned}]]')
hs_byte = "\ud83d".encode('utf-16-be', 'surrogatepass')
suspected_chars = [e for e in list(non_bmp) if e.encode('utf-16-be').startswith(hs_byte)]

Custom error handler
It is possible to write a custom error handler that doesn't mask the problem character:
def cp_replace_handler(exc):
  if isinstance(exc, (UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeTranslateError)):
    s = []
    for c in exc.object[exc.start:exc.end]:
      s.append(f'<{ord(c):04X}>')
    return (''.join(s), exc.end)
  else:
    raise TypeError("can't handle %s" % exc.__name__)
codecs.register_error('cp_replace', cp_replace_handler)

lone = 'a lone surrogate: \ud83d'
r1 = lone.encode('utf-16', 'cp_replace').decode('utf-16')
print(r1)
# a lone surrogate: <D83D>

surrogates = 'a surrogate pair: \uD83D\uDC08'
r2 = surrogates.encode('utf-16', 'cp_replace').decode('utf-16')
print(r2)
# a surrogate pair: <D83D><DC08>

